# How to escape spdlog message?

Tags: c++, c++17, spdlog

I'm using spdlog to log all messages. My log pattern is a JSON format. I'm escaping messages manually in all log calls. Is there any way exists to escape messages automatically in spdlog layer?

Sample of manually escaping:

```
spdlog::info(escape_message(data));
```

It should be automatically handled inside spdlog layer:

```
spdlog::info(data);
```

Comment: Can you give some example code showing what "manual escaping" looks like?

Comment: @Eric I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to solve it.

I should implement a custom `formatter` class and then in the `format` method, I escape the message by for example `escape_message(msg.payload.data())` and then call `spdlog::log(msg.source, msg.level, escape_message(msg.payload.data()))`, `spdlog::info` or ... inside this method.

**Note**: inside the `format` method I set a log pattern, because outside of the class, if I call `set_formatter`, then calling `set_pattern`, doesn't work well.

Comment: In case you had to do it the hard way... here's the easy explaination for it: https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting :-)

Comment: @andreee I exactly followed that road. but with a little customization

Answer (score 3):

Tell spdlog to format a single string, rather than interpreting the string itself as the format string:

```
spdlog::info("{}", data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried it but it doesn't work. This is the result: `{"message": "hi"hi"}`. I got the data by `std::cin` (`hi"hi`).

Comment: How are you constructing your JSON? It sounds like you're looking for json escaping, not spdlog escaping. Can you clarify your question? I was under the impresssion that `data` itself contained json, and you were running into trouble with embedded `{}` characters.

Comment: My data is not a JSON, actually, my spdlog pattern is a JSON format. For example: `{"message": "%v"}`. My data is a string.

Comment: @mortezaipo: That would be good to edit into your question. You're right, my answer does not help you for that case.

Comment: your answer did help me though! Thank you